# Android build error: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting following error when I try to build my app for release. I didn't get this error before update my Android studio and plugins. I'm using general libraries and nothing wrong in gradle configuration. Android Studio version is:

```
Android Studio 3.1.2
Build #AI-173.4720617, built on April 14, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
Gradle: 4.4
```

Here is the error log. As I understand, it does not implies specific part in my code.

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.abort(LintGradleExecution.java:199)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.runLint(LintGradleExecution.java:263)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.lintSingleVariant(LintGradleExecution.java:359)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.analyze(LintGradleExecution.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.api.ReflectiveLintRunner.runLint(ReflectiveLintRunner.kt:38)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintBaseTask.runLint(LintBaseTask.java:87)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintPerVariantTask.lint(LintPerVariantTask.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:780)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:747)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
```

As the logcat pointed out that, I can easily get rid of this problems adding following lines in app/gradle.

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

However this only incase the problem which I couldn't find what causes the error. Is this in bug Android Studio or Gradle. I couldn't find any answer on web related this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "What is the error?" -- you would need to tell us that. There should be messages in the Build output that tell you what Lint check failed. Or, run the Gradle `lint` task from the Gradle tool (it's in the "verification" category for your module) and check the report that it generates.

Comment: You're right but I copied the logcat in the question but errors are not in the java code or any code in my app. It indicate error at com.android.tools.lint.gradle . I'm currently checking your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. I didn't now that section. The problem is missing aposthrophes and missing translations.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem thanks to @CommonsWare. When I run the gradle-lint in the gradle>verification section I got the following logs. Appereantly, some missing apostrophes and several missing translations causes the error. If anyone encounteres similar error, just check translations before anything else.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

  Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
  ...

  Errors found:

  D:\Applications\APPFOLDER\app\src\main\res\values-fr\strings.xml:66: Error: Apostrophe not preceded by \ [StringEscaping]

  D:\Applications\GunlukBurclar\app\src\main\res\values-ar\strings.xml:35: Error: "settings_birthhour" is translated here but not found in default locale [ExtraTranslation]
      <string name="settings_birthhour">???? ???????:</string>
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      D:\Applications\APPFOLDER\app\src\main\res\values-az\strings.xml:35: Also translated here
      D:\Applications\APPFOLDER\app\src\main\res\values-de\strings.xml:35: Also translated here
      D:\Applications\APPFOLDER\app\src\main\res\values-es\strings.xml:35: Also translated here
      D:\Applications\APPFOLDER\app\src\main\res\values-fa\strings.xml:35: Also translated here
      D:\Applications\APPFOLDER\app\src\main\res\values-fr\strings.xml:35: Also translated here
      D:\Applications\APPFOLDER\app\src\main\res\values-ja\strings.xml:35: Also translated here
      D:\Applications\APPFOLDER\app\src\main\res\values-pt\strings.xml:35: Also translated here
      D:\Applications\APPFOLDER\app\src\main\res\values-ru\strings.xml:35: Also translated here
      D:\Applications\APPFOLDER\app\src\main\res\values-tr\strings.xml:59: Also translated here
      D:\Applications\APPFOLDER\app\src\main\res\values-zh\strings.xml:35: Also translated here



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 29s
33 actionable tasks: 17 executed, 16 up-to-date
00:44:14: Task execution finished 'lint'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when I tried to compile.

---

Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:

```
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...

----
```

After investigating several hours, he has found the solution. But I think the most important thing is the system that he has used.

In any Android file, in the left bar, we can click on the right button and access "Analyze", then we give an inspection code and we realize all Lint errors.

In my case, he corrected and got the problem. But this system gives a broad view of the health of the project code.

Resources:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint?hl=es-419